# How to upload Image to a specified folder in server using zk framework

Tags: java, zk

Help...i want to upload an image into specified folder in server PC and showed up as a background, but when i've see in zk demo in [this  link](https://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/file_handling/file_upload), i canot find where the image stored in server,and here is the code i have tried from zk demo :

```
<zk xmlns="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul">
    <button label="Upload Image" upload="true,maxsize=300">
        <attribute name="onUpload"><![CDATA[
            org.zkoss.util.media.Media media = event.getMedia();
            if (media instanceof org.zkoss.image.Image) {
                org.zkoss.zul.Image image = new org.zkoss.zul.Image();
                image.setContent(media);
                image.setParent(pics);
                 Messagebox.show("Not an image: "+media+"sipp "+pics);
            } else {
                Messagebox.show("Not an image: "+media, "Error", Messagebox.OK, Messagebox.ERROR);
                break;
            }
        ]]></attribute>
    </button>
    <separator />
    <vlayout id="pics" height="360px" style="overflow:auto" />
</zk>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this demo, the image is not stored in disk. Instead it was just in memory and would be expired after some time (or tomcat restarted).

If you need to store the image into a specific folder, you need to get the image stream from the Media object and write the stream to your specified file location.

Here is a reference: http://forum.zkoss.org/question/24566/how-to-save-fileupload-media-to-disk/

Comment: correct me if i wrong, so i want to store in a folder the code should look like this right?:

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("E://source//image"+media.getName()));

Comment: 1. You still need to write data to your output stream and close it. `fos.write(media.getByteData()); fos.close()`;  Close the stream in a try .. catch block is a good coding practice. 2. Single "/" is OK. 3. You may probably need "/" before filename. e.g. "E:/source/image/".  4. You need to aware that FileOutputStream will not auto create the folder (E:/source/image/) for you if it does not exists. It will just throw exception instead. You need to create it first or need extra coding to help you to create it.

Comment: okee thank you @Randy Huang,...it's more than enough to help me, i will try step by step in above